# WordPress - set display name from nickname with register process

Tags: wordpress, function, hook, registration

It is possible set display name from entered string into nickname registration field? I trying do this with simple hook, but after all it is not work.

```
function set_default_display_name( $user_id ) {
  $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $name = $user->nickname;
  $args = array(
    'ID' => $user_id,
    'display_name' => $name
  );
  wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_default_display_name' );
```

By default immediately after registration the display name was set from WP username (login) not nickname. Can sombody help me to set a display name from nickname?

Answer (score 0):

// change default display name format

```
add_action('user_register', 'registration_save_displayname', 1000);
function registration_save_displayname($user_id) {
if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'])){
    $pretty_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'display_name'=> $pretty_name) ) ;
}
```

}